# MainActivity jumps to the top of the stack when app is opened

Tags: java, android, android-activity, launchmode

I'm trying to develop an app with multiple activities, and I'm using the `singleInstance` launch mode so that there will not be multiple instances of the same activity. However, when I press the home button on the test phone (which calls `onStop()` but not `onDestroy()`, and I start the app again (by clicking on the icon), it brings me back to `MainActivity`. Investigating further, I found that the stack of activities (using the `adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run` command) were unaffected, except for `MainActivity`, which popped to the top of the stack.

I tried searching for this problem online but saw nothing similar. I might be just overlooking something obvious but I don't know. Thanks for any help!

EDIT ---

I will give an example of what occurs and what I expected. I start off the app at `MainActivity`, and then navigate to another activity (`AboutUs`) using a button. However, when I press the home button (on the phone) and click the app icon again, instead of going to `AboutUs`, it goes to `MainActivity`. `AboutUs` is still in the stack, but just under `MainActivity`. So, the stack was undisturbed except that `MainActivity` rose to the top.
[image]

Here is an image of the `Profiler` from Android Studio. As you can see, I clicked a button to go to `AboutUs`, and then hit the home button on the phone, which made a gap. After I clicked on the app again, it went back to `MainActivity`. `MainActivity` is both single instance and the launcher activity.

Comment: Before pressing the Home button, how many stacks are there in your app?

Comment: 3-4 activities, usually. However, this also occurs when there are only 2 activities in the stack.

Comment: Could you give a scenario about your case including expected and actual result?

Comment: Is MainActivity is launcher activity? Is MainActivity singleInstance? Which activity is visible on screen when you press the Home button? You said this behavior occurs when there is 2 activities in the stack, what are they?

Comment: I added an example, hope that clears things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the special launch mode `singleInstance` from the `<activity>` declaration for `MainActivity` in your manifest. This special launch mode is the cause of your problem. You should generally avoid the special launch modes `singleInstance` and `singleTask` because they cause more problems than they solve. These are only needed in very specific cases (like if you want to write your own HOME screen replacement).

Comment: thanks! this works :) just as a question, i find it weird to have multiple memories in the stack of the same activity, do people usually just do something in `onStop()` or `onPause()` to make sure that no conflicting things happen?

Comment: No, there are cases where you want to use the same `Activity`, but have multiple instances of it in your stack. It does cause some navigation problems, but there are cases where it makes sense. Mostly, though, it isn't necessary or desired, but luckily, if you program your app properly, you don't need to do anything special to prevent it.